# AttributeError when trying to use decode() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, decoding

I am using a program that worked fine in python 2.7, but is giving an error when I'm running it with python 3. The program is decoding strings to communicate with bluetooth.

The code section is:

```
senddata = ""
for byte in data:
    byte = str(byte)
    senddata += byte.decode ("hex")
self.controlsocket.send(senddata)
```

and I am getting the error below:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: in Python 3, all strings are already decoded already... remove ```.decode ("hex")```

Answer (score 2):

Text to text and binary to binary encodings were removed (not completely, but it's harder to use them) in Python 3, where `str` only has `encode` (to convert from text to binary) and `bytes` only has `decode` (to convert from binary to text).

To convert from a hex string to the raw underlying bytes, you can use `binascii.unhexlify` (portable between 2 & 3, but requires an import) or `bytes.fromhex` (only available on modern Python 3, but no import required).

You *can* still use the original binary to binary codecs via functions in the `codecs` module, but it's usually not worth the hassle; they give better equivalents in [the `codecs` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms).